# How to Keep the Suggested Place in GEOCOMPLETE?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I'm using google's geocomplete. So I'm using my $("#applicant-search-text") element to display the location.

When I type in "Bochu" for example, I get "Bochum, Germany". That's nice but when I click outside the input box, it reverts back to "Bochu".

```
 $("#applicant-search-text").geocomplete()
```

This allows the suggested location to appear. Then I tried this:

```
 $("#applicant-search-text").geocomplete()
      .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
      $.cookie("result",result.formatted_address);
 })

 $("#applicant-search-text").val($.cookie("result"));
```

It does not work. Please ask if the question is unclear.

Is there any way that I can retain the suggested place?

Comment: *I'm using google's geocomplete* ....there isn't a method `geocomplete` in any official (google-)maps-API, what are you using?

Comment: I'm using this plugin http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

Comment: Your code works for me with the plugin, are you sure that you've loaded the cookie-plugin too?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what you meant by cookie-plugin.

Comment: `$.cookie` is not a built-in jquery-method, you need a plugin: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie

Comment: Ah yes I have that installed. When you type in the location, press enter and select somewhere else, do you still get the value?

Comment: When an address has been geocoded and I load the page later, the field is pre-filled with the `formatted_address` from the cookie